# Compiling/linking shaders on Vivante GC1000 GPU (Galaxy Tab 3)

Tags: android, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I'am trying to use my custom shaders on a Galaxy Tab 3 but they are failing to compile or link. Here is the code.
This is the vertex shader

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

uniform sampler2D   u_texture;
varying vec2        blurs[8];
uniform vec2        blurSize;

#ifdef GL_ES
varying lowp vec2 v_texCoord;                    
#else                    
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
#endif

void main() 
{
    gl_Position = CC_MVPMatrix * a_position;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;

    blurs[0] = v_texCoord + vec2(-0.016, 0.0) * blurSize;
    blurs[1] = v_texCoord + vec2(-0.012, 0.0) * blurSize;
    blurs[2] = v_texCoord + vec2(-0.008, 0.0) * blurSize;
    blurs[3] = v_texCoord + vec2(-0.004, 0.0) * blurSize;
    blurs[4] = v_texCoord + vec2( 0.004, 0.0) * blurSize;
    blurs[5] = v_texCoord + vec2( 0.008, 0.0) * blurSize;
    blurs[6] = v_texCoord + vec2( 0.012, 0.0) * blurSize;
    blurs[7] = v_texCoord + vec2( 0.016, 0.0) * blurSize;
}
```

This is the fragment shader

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision lowp float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec2 blurs[8];
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

//uniform vec2 blurSize;
uniform vec4 substract;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0);
    gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, blurs[0])*0.0443;
    gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, blurs[1])*0.0776;
    gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, blurs[2])*0.1158;
    gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, blurs[3])*0.1473;
    gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord         )*0.1595;
    gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, blurs[4])*0.1473;
    gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, blurs[5])*0.1158;
    gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, blurs[6])*0.0776;
    gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, blurs[7])*0.0443;
}
```

In ipad, nexus devices and galaxy s3/s4 and note 3 it works fine. But in galaxy tab 3 (with the vivante gc1000 gpu) fails to compile or link; I do not know for sure which one is failing.
Here are the errors from logcat:

```
03-25 20:59:36.328 D/v_gal   (3167): [tid=3179] gcmONERROR: status=-10(gcvSTATUS_TOO_COMPLEX) @ _GenerateStates(10194)
03-25 20:59:36.328 D/v_gal   (3167): [tid=3179] gcmONERROR: status=-10(gcvSTATUS_TOO_COMPLEX) @ gcLINKTREE_GenerateStates(11342)
03-25 20:59:36.328 D/v_gal   (3167): [tid=3179] gcmERR_BREAK: status=-10(gcvSTATUS_TOO_COMPLEX) @ gcLinkShaders(7831)
03-25 20:59:36.328 D/cocos2d-x debug info(3167): cocos2d: ERROR: Failed to link program: 25
03-25 20:59:36.328 D/cocos2d-x debug info(3167): cocos2d: ERROR LOG PROGRAM: (null)
03-25 20:59:36.328 D/v_gal   (3167): [tid=3179] gl2mERROR: result=0x0501 @ glGetShaderiv(886)
03-25 20:59:36.328 D/cocos2d-x debug info(3167): cocos2d: ERROR LOG VERTEX: (null)
03-25 20:59:36.328 D/v_gal   (3167): [tid=3179] gl2mERROR: result=0x0501 @ glGetShaderiv(886)
03-25 20:59:36.328 D/cocos2d-x debug info(3167): cocos2d: ERROR LOG FRAG: (null)
```

ERROR LOG PROGRAM, ERROR LOG VERTEX, ERROR LOG FRAG are the calls to glGetProgramInfoLog and glGetShaderInfoLog. They are all returning null

Comment: Andres, does this blur work well for you? I assume there is a second pass for for the vertical blur, right? Do you have any screenshots?

Answer (score 2):

The Vivante GC1000 has a maximum of 8 varying vectors as returned by `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VARYING_VECTORS)`. A lot of ES devices have this same max. You shader currently using 9 varying vectors (`v_texCoord` + 8 blur coordinates), which is why the shader compiler is telling you the input is too complex. To resolve your issue, you can combine your 8 blur coordinate `vec2`'s as 4 `vec4`'s, using the `.xy` and `.zw` components as your original `vec2` offsets, for example

In the VS:

```
varying vec2 blurs[8];
…
blurs[0] = v_texCoord + vec2(-0.016, 0.0) * blurSize;
blurs[1] = v_texCoord + vec2(-0.012, 0.0) * blurSize;
```

can become

```
varying vec4 blurs[4];
...
blurs[0] = v_texCoord.xyxy + vec4(-0.016, 0.0, -0.012, 0.0) * blurSize;
```

And in the PS:

```
varying vec2 blurs[8];
…
gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, blurs[0])*0.0443;
gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, blurs[1])*0.0776;
```

becomes:

```
varying vec4 blurs[4];
…
gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, blurs[0].xy)*0.0443;
gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, blurs[0].zw)*0.0776;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: On some platforms and devices (eg: older iOS devices), swizzling the `vec4`'s to extract the `vec2` coordinates will reduce performance by causing dependent texture reads. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH7-SW18): "packing multiple sets of texture coordinates into a single varying parameter and using a swizzle command to extract the coordinates still causes a dependent texture read."